# Angular2 Final: Page Refresh error, 'Cannot GET' route. HashLocationStrategy failed

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have recently upgraded to Angular2 final release. I don't think this is a duplicate because [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) stopped working for me after the Angular2 Final/RC7 update. Previously, refreshing the page would fetch/GET the related route with a hash (#) and reload the page. Now, I get this error on any refreshed page:

[image]

I believe this is happening because it is trying to load `http://localhost:3000/main/home` instead of `http://localhost:3000/#/main/home`.

Any idea why `HashLocationStrategy` stopped working? Should I be importing `HashLocationStrategy` in my `@NgModule`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265536/angular-2-rc-4-hashlocationstrategy-no-longer-working

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-hashlocationstrategy- here is everything you'll need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `LocationStrategy` to `HashLocationStrategy` in your `AppModule`'s providers:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is still valid but there is a cleaner way:

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES_ARRAY, {useHash: true})
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [...],

})

export class AppModule { }
```