# Angular 2 - is base-href redundant when using HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Moving from ng1 to ng2, I would like to continue using `anchor hash '#'` for routing.

afaik, ng2 uses default *PathLocationStrategy* wherein we define a `<base-href="/">` which is the base path used by angular 2 router for client side routing, documented [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

Since I am using HashLocationStrategy, *will there be any problems if I remove `<base-href="">` from index.html?* I have created a small app with following routes and it seems to be working fine.

```
 export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',  component: AppComponent
  }, {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

thanks,

Comment: It should be `<base-href="/">` anyway. AFAIK you don't need it for `HashLocationStrategy`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer edited, thanks for confirming.

Comment: This QA gives you in details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265536/angular-2-rc-4-hashlocationstrategy-no-longer-working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using useHash: true with the Approute then no need to provide base-href
as it is redundant as both helps in refresh of page,but follow different concept.